# Is it possible for an aws s3-hosted website to subscribe to aws sns topic?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have a react frontend on s3 and a python backend on lambda. I need to implement asynchronous processing and am finding the best way to do this. Would it be possible for my react frontend to subscribe to an aws sns topic while it being on s3? Or does that require it have a server always running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could link the SNS topic to an SQS queue. You could make React consume the queue (using a Cognito token to provide credentials for it).

This way you could limit your surface but still allow appropriate access to the resources.

The direct answer to your question: No, you can't connect React directly to SNS.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just to make sure I understand the workflow you are proposing: React client sends request via API gateway which uses SNS topic to trigger lambda, then 'consumes' an SQS queue (= connecting to an SQS queue and waiting until a message comes through?).

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was thinking of. This way you can decouple lambda completion and just periodically poll the queue to see if it finished.

Comment: So I'll still need to implement some sort of exponential backoff polling. There's no way of having the app be directly notified once it's done?

Comment: You could use SQS long polling to reduce the amount of requests and get the fastest response time. The downside of this would be that you would need to publicly expose the queue. That's possible, but you really need to thing about how you secure that. Note that expontial backoff is never needed for SQS, as long as you are comfortable with the amount of requests.